# Calabash android automated tests for facebook login dialog

Tags: android, facebook-login, calabash, calabash-android

Is it possible to use Calabash to automate test cases for facebook login flow ?

Once the facebook login dialog is open, I can't seem to get hold of any of the input elements for email/password as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-android/7AhqqC1dyvY)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is webview facebook login, so we need to use calabash webview commands,

Here we go :

```
When(/^I login with facebook$/) do
    enter_text("android.webkit.WebView css:'input[name=\"email\"]'", "your_email")                        
    enter_text("android.webkit.WebView css:'input[name=\"pass\"]'", "your_password")              
    touch "android.webkit.WebView css:'button[name=\"login\"]'" 
end
```

here locator might be updated, please you updated locator from facebook login page. you can get the locators through web browser or chrome inspector.

More info : https://tech-tock-tech.blogspot.in/